# TypeScript import export behaviour of modules

Tags: javascript, module, typescript

I'm currently bundling typings d.ts files with my modules, and I came across this weird behaviour:

```
import * as validator from "./ZipCodeValidator" // works  
export * from "./ZipCodeValidator"; // works  
export import validator = require("./ZipCodeValidator"); // works  
export * as validator from "./ZipCodeValidator"; // does not work
```

Why does line 4 not show the same behaviour as line 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> export * as validator from "./ZipCodeValidator"; // does not work

It does not work because it is not valid ES6 syntax. The `import *` / `export *` are valid es6 syntaxes. The closes you can get with ES6 style module is:

```
import * as _validator from "./ZipCodeValidator" // works  
export validator = _validator;
```

Comment: I see. Thank you for the quick reply!